# For a basis of product topology on the $X \times X \times \cdots$，could there be infinitely many sets between two sets that are not the $X$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, products

By definition, a basis of the product topology on
$$
\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha 
$$
consists of sets of the form
$$
\prod_{\alpha \in J} U_\alpha, 
$$
where the $U_\alpha \neq X_\alpha$ only finitely many values of $\alpha$.

> Then, could there be infinitely many sets between $U_{\alpha_1} \neq X_{\alpha_1}$ and $U_{\alpha_2} \neq X_{\alpha_2}$?

The answer depends on the cardinality of the set $J$ and it's easy to see there are no such basis for the finite $J$. Then how about the countably infinite $J$？ If there were no such basis for the countably infinite $J$, why？

If there are, then how could the metric $D(x, y)$ induce the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ in this theorem?

> **Theorem.** Let $\bar{d}(a, b) = \min\{|a - b|, 1\}$ be the standard bounded metric on $\mathbb{R}$. If $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are two points of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$, define
> $$
> D(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) 
> = \sup \biggl\{ \frac{\bar{d}(x_i, y_i)}{i} \biggr\}.
> $$
> Then $D$ is a metric that induces the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$.

Comment: Any two points of $\omega$ are finite ordinals [natural numbers], so there's no sense of "infinitely many sets between".

Comment: @BrianMoehring You`re right！I make a silly question.  And how about the uncountable set ？

Comment: You need to have an order on $J$ for the more general question to even make sense.  There is no "before" or "after" (and hence no "between") if there is no order.

Comment: To be clear, the product $\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$ is a set of functions $\phi : J \to \bigcup_{\alpha\in J} X_\alpha$ such that $\phi(\alpha) \in X_\alpha$.  There is no order here at all unless it's inherited from $J$ itself.

Comment: @BrianMoehring thanks a lot！